# VS 10 mangles html comments?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, comments

Using the latest VS 10 we created html markup, then commented it with html comments.  The file on disk is not mangled, but when it renders, it renders the html comment tags, then removes some of the html markup within the commented tags:

Two questions (1) why would it not like the html comment tags and (2) why would it change the html content between the comment marks?  It physically removed the TD tag.  This is also using the 2010 MVC project.

Original:

```
 <!--
    <td width="165" valign="top">
       <a href="saving.html">
          <img src="images/marquee_edlp.jpg" width="165" height="180" alt=" " border="0">
       </a>
    </td>
 -->
```

Altered:

```
 <!-->
    <a href="saving.html">
       <img src="images/marquee_edlp.jpg" alt=" " border="0" height="180" width="165">
    </a>
 --&gt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are alone in this one.
Try the new RC bits to see if it fixes your problem.